# Python multiprocessing : processes do not start

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I'm new into `multiprocessing` in Python (2.7).

I try to run the following piece of code:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing

def func(x):
    print("start %s"%(x))
    sleep(x)
    print("end %s"%(x))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Process(target=func(10)).start()
    Process(target=func(1)).start()
```

This return something as :

```
start 10
end 10
start 1
end 1
```

While `start 1` and `end 1` should a priori appear before `end 10`.

I would appreciate help to understand what I might be missing here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You write:

```
Process(target=func(10)).start()
```

This means that the **`Process` never is given `func`**, it is given the **result of `func(10)`** since Python *first* evaluates the arguments left-to-right, and then passes the result of these evaluations to the outer function (here the `Process(..)` call).

In order to let the subprocess evaluate the function, you should write it like:

```
Process(target=func,args=(10,)).start()
```

Now you pass a **reference to the `func` function**, and you provide a **tuple of arguments `args`** with which the sub process is going to call the function. The subprocess will then call `func(10)` itself (and another subprocess will *almost* concurrently do the same with `func(1)`).

Comment: You were faster than me ;) When something is working as we don't expect, I recommend to print as mutch as we can, it helps you a lot to understand the way it works.

Comment: Shame on me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It is surprisingly easy to miss this when you have arguments no matter how good you understand  the difference between referencing and running the function

Answer (score 1):

When creating a `Process`, `target` should be function name only without arguments or parantheses and then you add `args=(your args)`. For example:

```
Process(target=func, args=(10,)).start()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Willem Van Onsem answer:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing

def func(x, called_from):
    print("start %s from %s"%(x, called_from))
    sleep(x)
    print("end %s from %s"%(x, called_from))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Process(target=func, args=(10,'1')).start()
    Process(target=func, args=(1,'2')).start()
```

You can use a lot of Process more to see when they're called and when they finish. Use other Process calls to see how they work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.