# Python multiprocessing with complex functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am aware that this question has already been asked, but I have done extensive research and am unable to figure my problem out.

My question has to do with running  **complex functions in parallel**.

I'm using selenium webdriver to automatically download files from one website and upload them to another, and I want these functions to run at the same time. They both use *while loops* and have layered conditional statements. I cannot  get the functions to run at the same time and would appreciate help. My code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing

def auto_download():

    # function logic here 

def auto_upload():

    # function logic here 

if __name__ == '__main__':

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto download', target=auto_download())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto upload', target=auto_upload())
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

This code runs the first function **auto_download()** but never starts the second.

However, if I run the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39260326/8869277), which is the same idea but with much simpler functions, it works fine.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def add():
    while True:
        print (1)
        time.sleep(3)

def sud():
    while True:
        print(0)
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=add)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='p', target=sud)
    p1.start()
    p.start()
```

Does my problem stem from the complexity of the functions I am trying to run simultaneously? Thanks ahead of time for your help!

EDIT: The solution (thanks to [Raw Dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004343/raw-dawg)) is that I was calling the function directly instead of in the process object. This is different than the solutions for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237326/python-multiprocessing-processes-do-not-start). The following code fixes the problem:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto download', target=auto_download)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto upload', target=auto_upload)
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Comment: It may have something to do with the content of your functions blocking each other. I had a similar issue some years ago. Is it possible to publish the function code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There is confidential information contained in the functions (I'm writing this program for a company), but I'll edit that out so I can try to express the function logic. I'll edit and update my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing : processes do not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237326/python-multiprocessing-processes-do-not-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem here - when you define your process with

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto download', target=auto_download())
```

You are running the function `auto_download()`. You are essentially starting this function in the main process, not in a Process object as you want to. For this reason `p1.start()` does not have the effect you want, as you aren't running these functions concurrently. Notice that in the second example in the Process signature you define it as

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=add)
```

with no parenthesis after `add`. Try it again with the following code:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto download', target=auto_download)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='auto upload', target=auto_upload)
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Comment: This fixed the problem! Thanks! Who would have thought the solution would be that simple. Much appreciated