# Python multi-processing processes not starting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing but I'm having trouble even starting the processes. Even the below code snippet from [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) does not print anything

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I went through this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237326/python-multiprocessing-processes-do-not-start) and their solution does not work for me.

I'm running python 3.8.2 on Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Outside jupyter notebook it ran fine, just as expected.

Comment: I ran under jupyter notebook, and the jupyter log had errors, (and it didn't do what you expected.)

Comment: As @RufusVS said, multiprocessing does not work in jupyter.

Comment: Yes! I now tried it outside using a console and it works fine, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

> Functionality within this package requires that the **main** module be
> importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines
> however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples,
> such as the multiprocessing.pool.Pool examples will not work in the
> interactive interpreter.

Try to execute it as a .py script via console.

Answer (score 1):

I used the newest version Anaconda 2020.11 to installed python Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4, JupterLab 2.26, and Spyder 4.1.5 etc., they all cannot run Process().start() called functions and do not show error.

The CMD.exe Prompt can run Process functions in .py files just fine.